# Intelligent compilers can't prevent infinite loops and SQL Cartesian joins

Tags: c#, sql, loops, cartesian-product

I am frustrated that my programs crash due to the following two problems:

- Infinite loops (e.g. C# or Javascript)
- SQL joins where I forgot to add a join clause

These seem to be preventable problems if the compilers were competent enough. How can these problems be prevented programatically?

Comment: Easy. Don't write infinite loops, and don't forget to add a JOIN.

Comment: What if a cartesian product is what your really wanted? They are occasionally useful, after all. But to answer the question, even if just in a cryptic comment, it's called [The Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). It turns out that detecting infinite loops is (probably) an [np-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) problem.

Comment: Compilers aren't supposed to be "intelligent", that's what programmers are supposed to provide in the relationship.  Compilers are just supposed to do what you tell them too.

Comment: Also, if you've studied programming, you may be aware that there is a certain problem with writing a program that can tell if other programs will halt or not.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It's more than NP-hard, it's impossible.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Check the np-hard wikipedia link in my comment. It calls out the Halting Problem as a specific example of np-Hard, but not np-Complete.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Check out the first sentence of the second paragraph of your first link.  I'm not sure what they're getting at in the other article, but the impossibility of the Halting Problem is pretty central to all of CS.

Answer (score 1):

Modern compilers can and do unroll loops for optimization reasons, but without knowing some of the data ahead of time, can't even make a heuristic for whether your loops will terminate (See: [dataflow programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming)). In fact, deciding whether your program itself will terminate is called the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

In other cases, you *want* infinite loops. For example a graphics engine usually does something like this:

```
while(true)
   render
```

As for your SQL joins... I guess it should be pretty obvious when you miss one. In some cases, an INNER JOIN is implied when you don't give one, so in that sense your compiler is fixing this exact issue.